# Mapping 2 tables one to many(with WHERE) to single entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Hope you can help me.

I have 2 tables in the db: Page and Page_L These tables are configured with one to many relation in the db where Page is the main  table while Page_L is the dependent one.

The structure of table Page is :

```
Int IdPage (PK)
Int Order Not Null
```

The structure of table Page_L is:

```
Int IdPage_L (PK)
Int IdPage Not Null 
Int IdLanguage Not Null
Varchar(255) Title
Varchar(MAX) Description
```

I would like to map these 2 tables onto a single class.

I have developed this code but the result doesn't satisfy me:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
                : base("ConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Page> Pages
    {
                get { return Set<Page>(); }
    }

    public IDbSet<Page_L> Page_Ls
    {
                get { return Set<Page_L>(); }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

public class Page
{
    [Key]
    public IdPage Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Page_L> Page_Ls { get; private set; }
}

public class Page_L
{
    [Key]
    public IdPage_L Id { get; set; }
    public int IdPage { get; set; }
    public int IdLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int LanguageID = (int)System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LanguageID"];
    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();
    var page = context.Pages.First();

    var page_L = page.Page_Ls.Where(p=>p.IdLanguage==LanguageID).FirstOrDefault();
    if(page_L!=null)
        Response.Write(page_L.Title);
}
```

In Page_Load Method I get the first page searching the `First()` result of `.Where(p=>p.IdLanguage==LanguageID)`.
I want bypass this, merging Page and Page_L filtered by LanguageID in AppSettings, so I can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();
    var page = context.Pages.First();

    Response.Write(page.Title);
}
```

I've tried to use Page_L such as an interface of Page but seems it does not work.

Thanks
Damiano